# How do I get the boss rush?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I killed Mom. Not the first time, probably not the last time either, but this time I noticed a large hole in the wall, not like a secret room, but way bigger. Inside I had a choice of loot and then waves upon waves of bosses. And then more reward. It was fun.

What can I do to guarantee/increase my chances of this boss rush happening?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to beat Mom in The Depths / Necropolis in less than 20 minutes from the start of the run.  Boss Rush will always appear if you do.

Note that it unlocks a different item/achievement for each character you beat Boss Rush with.

Comment: Note that it's Mom, *not* Mom's Heart.

Comment: Oh, so *that* is what that timer indication is for. That would've been my next question.